# How to prove the Jordan's Inequality?

Tags: limits, inequality, self-learning

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to prove it by using the concepts related to limit?

Comment: Hi, what did you mean by :'using the concepts related to limit?'

Comment: There are many ways to do this. For example, you could study the function $f(x)=\sin x-\frac2\pi x$ on $(0,\frac\pi2)$, or observe that the sine function is concave on $(0\frac\pi2)$.

Answer (score 6):

Notice that |sin(x)|=sin(|x|) and without loss of generality
assume that $0\leq x\leq \frac{\pi}2$.
Let $x_0=\arccos(\frac{2}\pi)$ so that for $x\leq x_0$ we have $\cos(x)\geq \frac{2}\pi$ and thus,
$$
\sin(x)=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x} \cos(y)dy \geq \displaystyle\int_{0}^{x}\frac{2}\pi dy=\frac{2}\pi x
$$
while for $x\geq x_0$  we have $\cos(x)\leq \frac{2}\pi$ and thus,
$$
\sin(x)=1-\displaystyle\int_{x}^{\frac{\pi}2 } \cos(y)dy \geq 1-\displaystyle\int_{x}^{\frac{\pi}2 }\frac{2}\pi dy=1-\frac{2}\pi(\frac{\pi}2-x)=\frac{2}\pi x
$$

NB: the nicest way to do it is as @Etienne said is the concavity of sin: The sine function is concave on $[0,\frac{\pi}2]$ because $f '(x) = \cos (x)$ is decreasing on $[0,\frac{\pi}2]$.

Thus,
$$\underbrace{\sin( x)}_{\sin \text{curve}} \geq \overbrace{\dfrac{2}{\pi} x}^{\text{line joining 0 and $\pi$/2}}$$

Comment: Thanks! But also, I would like to know how to prove it by concavity of sin, would you mind explaining to me?

Comment: @user100523 I edited :)